# Parsing xml with "not well-formed" characters in python

Tags: python, xml, regex

I am getting xml data from an application, which I want to parse in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

xml_file = 'tickets_prod.xml'
xml_file_handle = open(xml_file,'r')
xml_as_string = xml_file_handle.read()
xml_file_handle.close()

xml_cleaned = re.sub(u'[^\x01-\x7f]+',u'',xml_as_string)
root = ET.fromstring(xml_cleaned)
```

It works for smaller datasets with example data, but when I go to real live data, I get

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 364658, column 72
```

Looking at the xml file, I see this line 364658:

```
WARNING - (1 warnings in check_logfiles.protocol-2013-05-28-12-53-46) - ^[[0:36mnotice: Scope(Class[Hwsw]): Not required on ^[[0m</description>
```

I guess it is the `^[` which makes python choke - it is also highlighted blue in vim. Now I was hoping that I could clean the data with my regex substitution, but that did not work.

The best thing would be fixing the application which generated the xml, but that is out of scope. So I need to deal with the data as it is. How can I work around this? I could live with just throwing away "illegal" characters.

Comment: You could try with beautiful soup which did a very good job on escaping invalid characters for me.

Comment: Looks like some overly clever guy wanted to have bold or colored output on his tty for this warning. You should remove everything from the escape up to the following 'm'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already do:

```
xml_cleaned = re.sub(u'[^\x01-\x7f]+',u'',xml_as_string)
```

but the character `^[` is probably Python's `\x1b`.  If xml.parser.expat chokes on it, you need simply to clean up more, by only accepting some characters below 0x20 (space).  For example:

```
xml_cleaned = re.sub(u'[^\n\r\t\x20-\x7f]+',u'',xml_as_string)
```

Comment: Just wondering: is there a good ressource where I can look up how special characters like `^[`  are sometimes represented? I have been stumbling uppon problems like this more then once, and would like to to know how to handle these in the future.

Comment: In two words, Python uses `\xNN` systematically except for `\t \n \r`.  On Unix the characters 0 to 31 are generally written as `\@`, `\A`, ..., `\Z`, `\[`, `\\ `, `\]`, `\^`, `\_`, i.e. using the characters 64 to 95 after the backslash.  There are still other representations but I can't point you to a guide...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but stumbled upon the following url that has a list of all of the primary characters and their encodings.

https://medium.com/interview-buddy/handling-ascii-character-in-python-58993859c38e